# What are the efficient ways to assign values to 2D numpy arrays as functions of indicies

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy

It may be a stupid question but I couldn't find a similar question asked(for now). 
For example, I define as function called f(x,y)

```
def f(x, y):
    return x+y
```

Now I want to output a 2D numpy array, the value of an element is equal to its indices summed, for example, if I want a 2x2 array:

```
arr = [[0, 1],
       [1, 2]]
```

If I want a 3x3 array, then the output should be:

```
arr = [[0, 1, 2], 
       [1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4]]
```

It's not efficient to assign the values one by one, especially if the array size is large, say 10000*10000, which is also a waste of the quick speed of numpy. Although it sounds quite basic but I can't think of a simple and quick solution to it. What is the most common and efficient way to do it?

By the way, the summing indices just an example. I hope that the method can also be generalized to arbitrary functions like, say,

```
def f(x,y):
    return np.cos(x)+np.sin(y)
```

Or even to higher dimensional arrays, like 4x4 arrays.

Comment: Only given a function (with two parameters, say `f(x, y)`), I want to output a 2D-array, in which each element of the array is equal to `f(i, j)`, where `i`, `j` being the indices of the element in the array.

Comment: @erip I believe `arr = [[0, 1], [1, 2]]` *is* the output for *any* 2x2 array. Add the row index and column index (0-based) of each element of any 2x2 array and...

Comment: @TrebledJ Exactly. `arr` was the output. The `0` comes from the indicies, (0,0), summing them up gives 0. The `2` comes from the indicies (1,1), summing them up gives 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.indices`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html), which returns an array representing the indices of a grid; you'll just need to sum along the 0 axis:

```
>>> a = np.random.random((2,2))
>>> np.indices(a.shape).sum(axis=0) # array([[0, 1], [1, 2]])
>>> a = np.random.random((3,3))
>>> np.indices((3,3)).sum(axis=0) #array([[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]])
```

Comment: Thank you. But how can the method be generalized to an arbitrarily defined `f(x,y)`?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: with `x,y = (10000, 10000)` chances are that, depending on the machine, he's going to get a `MemoryError`, right?

Comment: There's no general answer if you're hoping to leverage numpy vectorization. You can use calls from `numpy` directly instead of methods of the nd-arrays; e.g., `np.sum(np.indices((3,3)), axis=0)` and `np.sum(np.cos(np.indices((3,3))), axis=0)`.

Comment: So if the function is very general, or may not even have a closed-form, that I hope to use some function previously defined, the best thing I can do is to assign the values one by one using for loops?

Comment: If `f(x,y)` only works with scalar `x,y` values, there's no fast alternative to python iteration.  You have to call it once for each `x,y` pair.  Your samples, though, work with array values, taking advantage of the compiled `numpy` operators.  If you want fast `numpy` use the building blocks that it provides,